# SQL Error - Array

Tags: sql, arrays

I get this error when users submit a form.
It appears to have no obvious impact i.e. all data is saved etc however, I have had to hide sql errors which means if there are other errors, I won't see them.
MSSQL Server
Any ideas?

error query

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => 
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]AG065239 [message] => [Microsoft][SQL
 Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]AG065239 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] =>
 01000 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]j 
[message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]j ) )
```

Comment: Where is this form that you mentioned?

Comment: And where is the sql executed?

Comment: You have errors and stuff.

Comment: Difficult problems often require a review of the premises that are thought to be true. In your case, consider a review of this premise: "I have had to hide sql errors which means if there are other errors, I won't see them." You may have a constraint of not showing SQL errors to users, but that does not mean that you (the developer) cannot see them. Consider the creation of an error log table to record errors for later review. The users won't see this, but you can. The error log table rows will need to be deleted after X days, but that effort is well worth the feedback benefit.